# Oracle data buffering

Tags: database, oracle

I have live audio that I would like to feed into a oracle database.  I would then like the clients to be able to connect to the audio and be able to listen to any point of the live feed. Currently I have it setup to play audio from committed blobs but any raw seek'able data would be fine.

The question is how exactly do I stream raw data into a instantly available destination/source? I have thought about using Advanced Queues but that has a random seeking problem. I have though about creating table and just putting raw chucks into but seems like it would be quite expensive and dirty.

Is there some way I can create a multi consumer blob or some sort of multi consumer buffer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't store the audio in the database.  Put the audio in a file on the filesystem and store a pointer to it in the DB.  The "multi-consumer blob" is just a filesystem file.

Comment: A BFile worked perfectly. A source can create a record with a BFile column, then actively write to that file though the OS and have as many sources as I want read from that file.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say this a non-friendly concept for a RDBMS. Generally while data is being inserted/updated in a database it isn't available for other sessions to use (or, in regard to updated data, the pre-update data is returned until the change is committed).

Once the audio is completed and committed to the database, the issue is very different.

I'd look for a dedicated application for streaming the live audio, and have the database as just another subscriber to that stream, recording it to the database.

Comment: I actually thought of this and was my initial route. Oracle actually has a plugin to Windows Media services that should have made this a trivial task. We ran into many problems with the plugin and weren't happy about the additional point of failure. The above answer of bfiles worked perfectly because bfiles are non transactional.